# Can `printf()` have a macro parameter?

Tags: c++, c, macros, printf

I am using the following `printf` function:

```cpp
    printf("%-8s%-21s%-17s%-6s\n", "index", "Name", "Effect", "Type");
```

However, instead of "8", I'd like to use a pre-defined macro:

```cpp
#define NAME_SIZE 8
```

When I tried to replace it, the IDE doesn't recognise it and gives the error: `Invalid conversion specifier N` (the first letter of the macro). I tried putting the macro name in `()` brackets or putting an interval these but didn't work either. So I wonder: is it even possible to put a macro as a parameter in a `printf` function and if yes, how? I am sorry for such a strange question but I couldn't find any information.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it? Sometimes the IDEs show false positive errors.

Comment: If you can define as `"8"` then would `printf("%-"NAME_SIZE"s%-21s%-17s%-6s\n", "index", "Name", "Effect", "Type");`do what you want?

Comment: You can use the `*` in place of the explicit number and pass the value as an `int` argument before the corresponding string: `printf("%-*s%-21s%-17s%-6s\n", (int)(NAME_SIZE), "index", "Name", "Effect", "Type");`

Comment: @Yunnosch I am using the macro for an array size, so it doesn't work exactly how I wanted. Thank you nevertheless.

Comment: @chqrlie That's what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can indeed do this (although in your specific case you can pass the parameter width which is a better method). Indeed some of the standard libraries for C and C++ exploit this (or put another way, ratify this as a legitimate technique), for example with PRId64 for the correct formatting of int64_t:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
int64_t t = 0;
printf("%" PRId64 "\n", t);
```

In your case, you need

```
#define NAME_SIZE "8"
```

along with

```
printf("%-"NAME_SIZE"s%-21s%-17s%-6s\n", "index", "Name", "Effect", "Type");
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you can define the macro slightly differently:

If you can define as `#define NAME_SIZE "8"` then `printf("%-"NAME_SIZE"s%-21s%-17s%-6s\n", "index", "Name", "Effect", "Type");` would do what I understand to be your goal.

This is because the compiler will concatenate directly adjacent string literals like `"a""b"` to `"ab"`.

If the macro has to be precisely as shown, you'd have to take a detour via using the `#` operator in another level of macro.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE( X )   #X

int main(void) 
{
    printf("%-" SIZE( 8 ) "s%-21s%-17s%-6s\n", "index", "Name", "Effect", "Type");
    printf("%-8s%-21s%-17s%-6s\n", "index", "Name", "Effect", "Type");
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
index   Name                 Effect           Type  
index   Name                 Effect           Type
```

Comment: Looks good to me.  Then `X` could also be used as an integer constant elsewhere.  `#define X 8  printf("pi to %d places: %." SIZE( X ) "f\n", X+1, X, acos(-1));` to print pi at some constant precision.  This is more valuable with `scanf()`, than `printf()` though as `printf()` has a _width_ specifier option.